# Sqlite FTS4 Get rows with Order of terms in query

Tags: sqlite

My virtual table is:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE docs USING fts4();

INSERT INTO docs(docid, content) VALUES(1, 'sqlite is a database');
INSERT INTO docs(docid, content) VALUES(2, 'my database is sqlite');
```

When I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'sqlite AND database';
```

it returns both 2 records in the table because both of them contain the term "sqlite" and the term "database".

Now, I want to search for records that contain the term "sqlite" and the term "database" with this rule:

The order in which the terms appear in the document has to be the same as the order in which they appear in the query (document with docid 1 only).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

[FTS queries](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#full_text_index_queries) cannot restrict the order of terms, except for phrase searches, which require consecutive terms (e.g., `"sqlite database"` would not match `sqlite is a database`).

You have to restrict the results afterwards:

```
SELECT ... WHERE docs MATCH 'sqlite AND database'
             AND content LIKE '%sqlite%database%';
```

Comment: Does the speed slow down with this solution?

Comment: That depends on how many rows are eliminated by the second check.

Comment: Thank you, Is it possible to use Offsets() function results to restrict the query results? (2-th integer in set of four integers is: The term number of the matching term within the full-text query expression)

Comment: It's possible, but would not be faster than LIKE unless the text is very large.

Comment: my texts in each records are one page of a book and I have 1000000 records. can you help me to use the Offset() function to do this?

Comment: your first solution not work correctly because if there is a record with this content: "there are any databases. sqlite is a database" then the "SELECT ... WHERE docs MATCH 'sqlite AND database'
             AND content LIKE '%sqlite%database%';" shows it while it should not be appear in results.

Comment: But the two terms *do* appear in the correct order. Why should this row not match?

Comment: Because we want records that the term "sqlite" is the first term appear in the content and the term "database" is the second